# Programmatically Configure HTTPS Only for Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Is there a way to programmatically enable the `HTTPS Only` flag on a custom domain of an Azure Function App? I've been using the CLI quite extensively and have been pleased with the comprehensive coverage it provides, but I can't seem to figure this out out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the command as below.

```
az functionapp update  --name '<function name>' --resource-group '<resource group name>' --set httpsOnly=true
```

[image]

Comment: Worked great, thank you.  I didn't realize you could set any of the properties like that!  DUH!  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Good news!
There is support for `https-only=true` in `az functionapp create` since `az-cli` version 2.41.0:

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-create

[image]

Example of command:

```
az functionapp create \
    --name $APPNAME \
    --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP \
    --consumption-plan-location $LOCATION \
    --storage-account $STORAGEACCOUNTNAME \
    --app-insights-key $APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY \
    --functions-version 4 \
    --https-only true
```

After running the command you will get this in azure portal:

[image]